# Having display problems with my external screen (Macbook Pro M1 to LG Ultrafine for Mac)

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I'm having this weird problem with my MacBook Pro M1 connection with an LG Ultrafine for Mac external display. I'm using the Type C to Type C connection.

It used to function fine, but now I can't use the LG as an extended display since when I open windows on my Mac, the LG goes black. Checking open windows on LG shows this: [image]

The reverse happens when I open a window on the LG (i.e. the LG has the display but the Macbook goes black).

I've tried rebooting both my laptop and display multiple times, nothing. I can't close the black windows either.

Anyone have any solution to this?

Comment: Are you using fullscreen apps with System Prefs > Mission Control > Displays have separate Spaces **unchecked**?

Comment: @Tetsujin, Thanks for the advice, it's fixed now!